# Ways to build a set of linear independent vectors from an orthonormal basis.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Suppose I have an orthonormal basis $\{{\psi_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ for a Hilbert space $\cal H$.

Consider the elements
$\phi_n = \psi_{n+1}+ a \psi_n, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N, a \in \mathbb C$

Are $\{\phi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ linearly independent?

Comment: See how to ask a question here.   https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write out an arbitrary linear combination of $\{ \phi _n \} _n $ and use the fact that $ \{ \psi _n \} _n $ are linearly independent.